# SBT run statement shows: No main class detected

Tags: scala, sbt

I have created a web app and when I try to run with `sbt run`, it shows:

```
sbt run    
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /home/developer/scala/user-svc/target/scala-2.13
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/developer/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Set current project to scala-2-13 (in build file:/home/developer/scala/user-svc/target/scala-2.13/)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed May 23, 2020, 11:44:32 PM
```

The content of `build.sbt` is:

```
val Http4sVersion = "0.21.4"
val CirceVersion = "0.13.0"
val Specs2Version = "4.9.3"
val LogbackVersion = "1.2.3"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    organization := "io.example",
    name := "user-svc",
    version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.2",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-jetty" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-jetty-client" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-dsl" % Http4sVersion,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % CirceVersion,
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % Specs2Version % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % LogbackVersion
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.10.3"),
    addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.1"),
  )

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-language:postfixOps",
  "-feature",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
)
```

The folder structure should be correct:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a main class, the entrypoint to your program defined. On JVM [you have to have](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2) at least one class which defines

```
public static void main(args: String[])
```

which in Scala's case means something like

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ...
  }
}
```

If there is exactly one such class, sbt can detect it, if there are more, you have to tell sbt which one to use using:

```
mainClass := Some("name.of.my.Main")
```

in order to call `run`. If you run JAR this class can be specified using `manifest.mf` or passed explicitly.